# How to search in subkey's under a JSON response with Python

Tags: python, json, search

Python newbie needs some help.

Looking for getting data from my Parrot Flower Pot to Domoticz I have found a script, but is was outdated. I have managed to get is working, but only 1 problem remains... :(

I have a json response from a Parrot API with the following data:

```
u 'locations': [{
        u 'first_sample_utc': u '2018-01-27T18:34:59Z',
        u 'air_temperature': {
            u 'status_key': u 'status_ok',
            u 'gauge_values': {
                u 'current_value': 16.2531360227017,
                u 'min_threshold': 7.0,
                u 'max_threshold': 35.0
            },
            u 'instruction_key': u 'air_temperature_good',
            u 'next_analysis_datetime_utc': None
        },
        u 'processing_uploads': False,
        u 'user_sharing': {
            u 'first_all_green': {
                u 'sharing_status': u 'conditions_unmet'
            }
        },
        u 'battery': {
            u 'gauge_values': {
                u 'current_value': 100,
                u 'min_threshold': 0,
                u 'max_threshold': 100
            }
        },
        u 'global_validity_datetime_utc': u '2018-01-31T00:19:56Z',
        u 'location_identifier': u 'kOzNaDnxWi1517078855393',
        u 'watering': {
            u 'status_key': u 'status_ok',
            u 'automatic_watering': {
                u 'next_watering_datetime_utc': u '2018-01-29T00:21:29Z',
                u 'instruction_key': u 'automatic_watering_good',
                u 'last_watering_datetime_utc': None,
                u 'done_action_datetime_utc': None,
                u 'status_key': u 'status_ok',
                u 'gauge_values': {
                    u 'current_value': 81,
                    u 'min_threshold': 0,
                    u 'max_threshold': 100
                },
                u 'full_autonomy_days': None,
                u 'predicted_action_datetime_utc': u '2018-01-29T00:21:30Z'
            },
            u 'instruction_key': u 'automatic_watering_good',
            u 'soil_moisture': {
                u 'status_key': u 'status_ok',
                u 'gauge_values': {
                    u 'current_value': 64.8775787353516,
                    u 'min_threshold': 32.0,
                    u 'max_threshold': None
                },
                u 'instruction_key': u 'soil_moisture_good',
                u 'predicted_action_vwc_value': None,
                u 'predicted_action_datetime_utc': None
            }
        },
        u 'last_sample_utc': u '2018-01-29T00:19:56Z',
        u 'growth_day': False,
        u 'total_sample_count': 120,
        u 'light': {
            u 'status_key': u 'status_ok',
            u 'gauge_values': {
                u 'current_value': 0.00263333333333334,
                u 'min_threshold': 5.0,
                u 'max_threshold': 99.0
            },
            u 'instruction_key': u 'light_too_low',
            u 'next_analysis_datetime_utc': None
        },
```

And the code to search and parse the data to Domoticz from the json:

```
for loc in status_locations:
plante=('{plant}:'.format(plant=loc2name[loc['location_identifier']].encode('utf-8')))
print plante
if plante == Nom_Plante:
    print('Found Plant')
    for metric in ['light', 'soil_moisture']:
        data = loc[metric]
        if debug!=0:
            print ('############# metrics###############')
            print('  {metric}:'.format(metric=metric))
            #print('    instruction_key: {0}'.format(data['instruction_key']))
            print('#####################################')
        inst_key=format(data['instruction_key'])
        status_key=format(data['status_key'])


        if metric == 'light':
            domoticz_idx=str(periph_idx['Plante_Lumiere_Status'])
            maj_widget_alert(domoticz_idx,status_key,inst_key,battery_level)   

            z=data['gauge_values']
            # Conversion de la valeur en Lux (1 PAR = 53.93 Lux) 
            valeur=z['current_value']*53.93
            valeur="%.2f" % valeur
            domoticz_idx=str(periph_idx['Plante_Lumiere_Valeur'])
            maj_widget_texte(domoticz_idx,valeur,battery_level)

        if metric == 'soil_moisture':
            domoticz_idx=str(periph_idx['Plante_Humidite_Status'])
            maj_widget_alert(domoticz_idx,status_key,inst_key,battery_level)

            z=data['gauge_values']
            valeur="%.2f" % z['current_value']
            domoticz_idx=str(periph_idx['Plante_Humidite_Valeur'])
            maj_widget_texte(domoticz_idx,valeur,battery_level)
```

The search for the data under 'light' works, but the search for 'soil_moisture' not. I can see it has something to do with the reason that 'soil_moisture' is under a subkey of 'watering'. But how can I make the search for 'soil_moisture' work in this script like the 'light' data?

Any help would nice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your metric list to hold the object path instead of just the key of the first level.

**Example:**

**Change**

```
for metric in ['light', 'soil_moisture']:
        data = loc[metric]
```

**To**

```
for metric in [loc['light'], loc["watering"]['soil_moisture']]:
        print metric
```

Answer (score 0):

The `soil_moisture` object is data member of the `watering` object while `light` is a top-level object.

The `soil_moisture` object will need to be accessed via `watering` like so: `loc['watering']['soil_moisture']`.